# it is a binary search tree .there is an issue while deleting elements.why?

Tags: c

it is a binary search tree with inorder traversal. there is an issue while printing elements. I can't solve the issue. The `deletebst` is not working. It still displays same. It could be a semantic error also. Maybe there is issue in inserting. Or some issue in displaying inorderly.
I am using a double pointer in the search function and calling it in delete function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *llink;
    struct node *rlink;
};
typedef struct node bstnode;
bstnode *root = NULL;

void
insert(int ele)
{
    bstnode *cur,
    *prev,
    *temp;

    temp = (bstnode *) malloc(sizeof(bstnode));
    temp->data = ele;
    temp->llink = temp->rlink = NULL;
    cur = root;
    prev = NULL;
    if (root == NULL)
        root = temp;
    else {
        while (cur != NULL) {
            prev = cur;
            if (ele < cur->data)
                cur = cur->llink;
            else
                cur = cur->rlink;
        }
        if (ele < prev->data)
            prev->llink = temp;
        else
            prev->rlink = temp;
    }
}

void
inorder(bstnode * node)
{
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else if (node != NULL) {
        inorder(node->llink);
        printf("%d\n", node->data);
        inorder(node->rlink);
    }
}

bstnode *
search(int key, bstnode ** prev)
{
    bstnode *cur;

    (*prev) = NULL;
    cur = root;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (key == cur->data)
            return cur;
        else {
            (*prev) = cur;
            if (key < cur->data)
                cur = cur->llink;
            else {
                cur = cur->rlink;
            }

        }

    }
    return cur;
}

void
deletebst(int ele)
{
    bstnode *cur,
    *prev,
    *insucc,
    *inprev;

    cur = search(ele, &prev);
    if (cur->llink != NULL && cur->rlink != NULL) {
        inprev = cur;
        insucc = cur->rlink;
        while (insucc->llink != NULL) {
            inprev = insucc;
            insucc = insucc->llink;
        }
        cur->data = insucc->data;
        if (inprev == cur) {
            inprev->rlink = insucc->rlink;
        }
        else
            inprev->llink = insucc->rlink;
        free(insucc);
        return;
    }
    if (cur->llink != NULL && cur->rlink != NULL) {
        if (cur == root) {
            root = cur->rlink;

        }
        else if (prev->llink == cur)
            prev->llink = cur->llink;
        else {
            prev->rlink = cur->llink;
        }
        cur = NULL;
        free(cur);
        return;
    }
    if (cur->llink == NULL && cur->rlink == NULL) {
        if (cur == root)
            root = NULL;
        else if (prev->llink == cur)
            prev->llink = NULL;
        else {
            prev->rlink = NULL;
        }
        return;
    }
}

int
main()
{
    insert(45);
    insert(76);
    insert(85);
    deletebst(76);
    inorder(root);
}
```

Comment: If you step through it in a debugger during a delete does anything seem wrong?

Comment: What I immediately find odd is three `if` statements with identical clauses, bet slightly different internals. Is this supposed to be a loop?

Comment: tadman is right, you have four possible combinations of links and you have only 3 tests, but you do one test twice. rewrite the delete function.

Comment: If you try to delete a non-existing key, you'll end up dereferencing a NULL pointer and your program will crash.